# How can I parse this Date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, date, datetime, time

I get date from a JSON such as:

```
2013-11-26T11:36:32+0000
```

And I want as dd-MM-yyyy h: hh.mm, such as `26/11/2013 h: 11:36`. So this is my code:

```
var dateParsed = new Date(Date.parse(feed.created_time));
console.log(dateParsed.toString('dd-MM-yyyy h: hh.mm'));
```

but it prints:

```
Tue Nov 26 2013 12:36:32 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)
```

Where am I wrong on this parsing?

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong with your parse. Its your `toString` automatically handling timezones.

Comment: So what should I do? :O

Comment: Use the date object you've created and it's various methods to output the date and time in your required format?

Comment: Such as? Can you give an example?

Comment: @markzzz I've added an example below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
function padDateTime(dt) { //Add a preceding zero to months and days < 10
    return dt < 10 ? "0"+dt : dt;
}

var dateParsed = new Date(Date.parse(feed.created_time));
var dd = padDateTime(dateParsed.getDate());
var mm = padDateTime(dateParsed.getMonth()+1);
var yyyy = dateParsed.getFullYear();
var hrs = padDateTime(dateParsed.getHours());
var mins = padDateTime(dateParsed.getMinutes());

var myDateTimeString = dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yyyy+" h: "+hrs+":"+mins;
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37wmF/)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with what javascript is parsing the date as. But specifically if you want date-time in your convenient format you can use [dateformat.js](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) library to format date and time.

Using the functions in the link, you can get desired results simply by following code:

```
console.log(dateParsed.format('dd/mm/yyyy ') + 'h: ' + dateParsed.format('hh:MM'));
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

Couple of useful functions I came across some time ago:

Usage

```
var dateParsed = new Date(Date.parse(feed.created_time));
var newdate = dateFormat(dateParsed, "dd-MM-yyyy h: hh.mm");
```

Functions

```
 * Date Format 1.2.3
 * (c) 2007-2009 Steven Levithan <stevenlevithan.com>
 * MIT license
 *
 * Includes enhancements by Scott Trenda <scott.trenda.net>
 * and Kris Kowal <cixar.com/~kris.kowal/>
 *
 * Accepts a date, a mask, or a date and a mask.
 * Returns a formatted version of the given date.
 * The date defaults to the current date/time.
 * The mask defaults to dateFormat.masks.default.
 */


var dateFormat = function () {
var token = /d{1,4}|m{1,4}|yy(?:yy)?|([HhMsTt])\1?|[LloSZ]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'/g,
    timezone = /\b(?:[PMCEA][SDP]T|(?:Pacific|Mountain|Central|Eastern|Atlantic) (?:Standard|Daylight|Prevailing) Time|(?:GMT|UTC)(?:[-+]\d{4})?)\b/g,
    timezoneClip = /[^-+\dA-Z]/g,
    pad = function (val, len) {
        val = String(val);
        len = len || 2;
        while (val.length < len) val = "0" + val;
        return val;
    };

// Regexes and supporting functions are cached through closure
return function (date, mask, utc) {
    var dF = dateFormat;

    // You can't provide utc if you skip other args (use the "UTC:" mask prefix)
    if (arguments.length == 1 && Object.prototype.toString.call(date) == "[object String]" && !/\d/.test(date)) {
        mask = date;
        date = undefined;
    }

    // Passing date through Date applies Date.parse, if necessary
    date = date ? new Date(date) : new Date;
    if (isNaN(date)) throw SyntaxError("invalid date");

    mask = String(dF.masks[mask] || mask || dF.masks["default"]);

    // Allow setting the utc argument via the mask
    if (mask.slice(0, 4) == "UTC:") {
        mask = mask.slice(4);
        utc = true;
    }

    var _ = utc ? "getUTC" : "get",
        d = date[_ + "Date"](),
        D = date[_ + "Day"](),
        m = date[_ + "Month"](),
        y = date[_ + "FullYear"](),
        H = date[_ + "Hours"](),
        M = date[_ + "Minutes"](),
        s = date[_ + "Seconds"](),
        L = date[_ + "Milliseconds"](),
        o = utc ? 0 : date.getTimezoneOffset(),
        flags = {
            d:    d,
            dd:   pad(d),
            ddd:  dF.i18n.dayNames[D],
            dddd: dF.i18n.dayNames[D + 7],
            m:    m + 1,
            mm:   pad(m + 1),
            mmm:  dF.i18n.monthNames[m],
            mmmm: dF.i18n.monthNames[m + 12],
            yy:   String(y).slice(2),
            yyyy: y,
            h:    H % 12 || 12,
            hh:   pad(H % 12 || 12),
            H:    H,
            HH:   pad(H),
            M:    M,
            MM:   pad(M),
            s:    s,
            ss:   pad(s),
            l:    pad(L, 3),
            L:    pad(L > 99 ? Math.round(L / 10) : L),
            t:    H < 12 ? "a"  : "p",
            tt:   H < 12 ? "am" : "pm",
            T:    H < 12 ? "A"  : "P",
            TT:   H < 12 ? "AM" : "PM",
            Z:    utc ? "UTC" : (String(date).match(timezone) || [""]).pop().replace(timezoneClip, ""),
            o:    (o > 0 ? "-" : "+") + pad(Math.floor(Math.abs(o) / 60) * 100 + Math.abs(o) % 60, 4),
            S:    ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"][d % 10 > 3 ? 0 : (d % 100 - d % 10 != 10) * d % 10]
        };

    return mask.replace(token, function ($0) {
        return $0 in flags ? flags[$0] : $0.slice(1, $0.length - 1);
    });
};
}();

// Some common format strings
dateFormat.masks = {
"default":      "ddd mmm dd yyyy HH:MM:ss",
shortDate:      "m/d/yy",
mediumDate:     "mmm d, yyyy",
longDate:       "mmmm d, yyyy",
fullDate:       "dddd, mmmm d, yyyy",
shortTime:      "h:MM TT",
mediumTime:     "h:MM:ss TT",
longTime:       "h:MM:ss TT Z",
isoDate:        "yyyy-mm-dd",
isoTime:        "HH:MM:ss",
isoDateTime:    "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss",
isoUtcDateTime: "UTC:yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss'Z'"
};

// Internationalization strings
dateFormat.i18n = {
dayNames: [
    "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat",
    "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
],
monthNames: [
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec",
    "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
]
};

// For convenience...
Date.prototype.format = function (mask, utc) {
return dateFormat(this, mask, utc);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's `toString` doesn't let you pass in arguments for formatting. `toString` just prints exactly what you got. You can build the string yourself using `getHours`, `getMonth`, etc. Also, various libraries address this, such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

If you are targeting very new versions of certain browser (Chrome and IE 11), [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) is available as a built-in means of doing this. Eventually we'll get to a point where this is pretty standard, but we aren't there yet.